# How to get host domain from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get a fourth level domain by using the Request.Url.Host method but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

If the domain is "abc.def.somedomain.com" its only returning up to the third level "def.somedomain.com"

Comment: Have you looked at the "Authority" property?

Comment: Check the http headers for the request using Request.Headers you may find the complete domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` is what you need.